# Removing higher layer

Tags: jquery

I want to remove 8th layer upper than this layer.

so I wrote this code : http://jsfiddle.net/3JaGg/
this code work now, but I want to know is there any better way ?

because I use `parent()` for 8 times.

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
```

Note: I use many DIVs because I want rounding the corners with CSS2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `closest()`, this will traverse up the DOM to find the nearest element with the selector you provide - in your case, `closest(".popup")` will work.

```
$('.closeBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".popup").remove();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3JaGg/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method instead instead of multiple calls to `parent()`.

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

```
closest('.popup')
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3JaGg/3/)