# Add again after remove

Tags: jquery, dom

I removed an element with `remove()` as I said before in : [Removing higher layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381250/removing-higher-layer)

now when I click again on my link to open popup, the link cannot work because that layer removed before.

How can I remove the remove property from my element ?

**UPDATE:**

I use `requireJS` plugin to load a JS file when click on link :

```
$('a#addUser').click(function () {
    require (['controllers/users/add'],function() {
         $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

In controllers/users/add.js I have that popup, user can close popup, I don't have any problem up to here, the problem is when user click again on link and popup should be show again, but in my code that popup does not open again.

**ANSWER:**
The problem is requreJS, because this plugin allow me to load my javascript just one time,

I should use `$.getScript()` instead of requreJS

Comment: maybe you can just hide it? or save it on some veriable and add it later

Comment: Have you tried `.detach()` instead? In any case, you have to keep a reference to the element. How are you trying to add the element again? You should post some code!

Comment: @DanBarzilay I loaded a JS file in my popup, so if user click on link I should load again that file in popup, but after removing tag I cannot display that again

Answer (score 4):

Remove is not a property, the element is actually gone. To just hide it temporarly use [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/), to detach it an reattach it later use [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

```
var elm = $("#elementID").detach();

$(button).on('click', function() {
    elm.appendTo('#popupID');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you remove it (which can't be restored!) clone it.

```
var cloned = $('.foo').clone();
$('.clone').remove();
```

[**Updated your Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3JaGg/4/)

I'm not sure you're doing the right thing with the removing but I answered your's question.
You might want to hide and show the element inside of completely remove it from the DOM.

Comment: I don't want clone my element, because when user click on link I want to send the request to server again to receive new code (please read update in my question)

Comment: @MajAfy. I'm afraid there are too much info missing in your question, and the update doesn't help much either. If you could show us a fiddle you would get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var copyofpopup = $('.popup').clone(true);
$('.popup').remove();

$('OPEN_POPUP_LINK').on('click', function() {
  copyofpopup.appendTo('SOMETARGET');
});
```

**NOTE** Its is better just show/hide (toggle) instead of remove